# IntelliJ - include pom.xml dependencies in lib directory

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I just converted an embedded Tomcat web app project to Maven in IntelliJ.

Before converting, I had all the external libraries (jars) in a lib directory as part of the project itself.

After converting, the way I understand it, the dependencies referenced in pom.xml are sitting outside of the project in an .m2 directory (local repository) and can be included in the final application if packaged as an executable jar.

Is it possible to have the dependencies (jars) that are referenced in pom.xml continue to exist in the lib directory of the project? Obviously, they would also need to be synchronized every time the pom.xml changes.

The reason I need this weird set up is because I deploy the application by running rsync to the server and not by copying an executable jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>What you want is an [exploded war](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html). It creates an **exploded webapp** in a specified directory. All your dependent jar files will be included.</s>

You can copy all dependency jars into a target directory.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/libs</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

see [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html)

By default this goal is bound to phase process-sources. So simply a

```
mvn clean process-sources
```

will give you all dependency jars in the libs directory.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this. The application is really just a Java application with a main method and not deployed as a war file, but this could actually work.

Comment: This would entail an additional step for deployment for me. Currently I deploy directly from the project directory. I wish there was a way to have a local project directory with the jars. The other problem with this set up is that I wouldn't be able to continue to have the jars in my git repository.

Comment: Sorry for missing the embedded key word. I'll edit my answer.